# Scroll the cells using UI Testing

Tags: ios, uitableview, scroll, xctest

Is there a method like

```
- (void)scrollByDeltaX:(CGFloat)deltaX deltaY:(CGFloat)deltaY;
```

for iOS?

I think the above method is only for OSX.
I would like to scroll my tableview according to the deltavalues provided.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Oletha's answer was exactly what I was looking for but there are a couple of minor mistakes in the Objective-C example.  Since the edit was rejected, I'll include it here as a reply for anyone else that comes along:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *table = [app.tables elementBoundByIndex: 0];

// Get the coordinate for the bottom of the table view
XCUICoordinate *tableBottom = [table 
coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake( 0.5, 1.0)];

// Scroll from tableBottom to new coordinate
CGVector scrollVector = CGVectorMake( 0.0, -30.0); // Use whatever vector you like
[tableBottom pressForDuration:0.5 thenDragToCoordinate:[tableBottom coordinateWithOffset:scrollVector]];
```

Answer (score 7):

On iOS, you can use [`XCUIElement.press(forDuration:thenDragTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuielement/1618670-press) if you want to move in terms of elements.

To move in terms of relative co-ordinates, you can get the `XCUICoordinate` of an element, and then use [`XCUICoordinate.press(forDuration:thenDragTo:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/xctest/xcuicoordinate/1615003-press).

```
let table = XCUIApplication().tables.element(boundBy:0)

// Get the coordinate for the bottom of the table view
let tableBottom = table.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset:CGVector(dx: 0.5, dy: 1.0))

// Scroll from tableBottom to new coordinate
let scrollVector = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: -30.0) // Use whatever vector you like
tableBottom.press(forDuration: 0.5, thenDragTo: tableBottom.withOffset(scrollVector))
```

Or in Objective-C:

```
XCUIApplication *app = [[XCUIApplication alloc] init];
XCUIElement *table = [app.tables elementBoundByIndex: 0];

// Get the coordinate for the bottom of the table view
XCUICoordinate *tableBottom = [table coordinateWithNormalizedOffset:CGVectorMake(0.5, 1.0)];

// Scroll from tableBottom to new coordinate
CGVector scrollVector = CGVectorMake(0.0, -30.0); // Use whatever vector you like
[tableBottom pressForDuration:0.5 thenDragToCoordinate:[tableBottom coordinateWithOffset:scrollVector]];
```

Comment: This piece of code worked for me, but with some changes (I used it on WebView instead of table). First, `.coordinate` method has parameter with `z` in word `Normalized` (for Swift part); second, I had to position this normalized offset to center of the WebView (passing 0.5 for both `dx` and `dy`) because the WebView had some buttons over it at the bottom; third, I had to lower the initial press duration from 0.5 to 0.2 because holding for half a second caused WebView to select text.

Comment: Updated my snippet to have a z in normalized, sorry about that!

Answer (score 5):

This Swift4 version that worked for me. Hope it helps someone in the future.

```
let topCoordinate = XCUIApplication().statusBars.firstMatch.coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero)
let myElement = XCUIApplication().staticTexts["NameOfTextLabelInCell"].coordinate(withNormalizedOffset: .zero)
// drag from element to top of screen (status bar)
myElement.press(forDuration: 0.1, thenDragTo: topCoordinate)
```